# React useEffect() only run on first render with dependencies

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

There are several other SO questions on this where the answer is either to eliminate the dependencies complaints via ESLint (I'm using typescript) or to do something else to still allow the second parameter of useEffect to be `[]`. However per the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) this is not recommended. Also under the react useEffect docs it says

> If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect
>   will always have their initial values. While passing [] as the second
>   argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and
>   componentWillUnmount mental model, there are usually better solutions
>   to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React
>   defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing
>   extra work is less of a problem.

I have the following code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    container.current = new VisTimeline(container.current, items, groups, options);
  }, [groups, items, options]);
```

I want it to run only one time.

Is the only way around this to let it run each time and `useState` to track it has ran before like this:

```
  const [didLoad, setDidLoad] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!didLoad) {
      container.current = new VisTimeline(container.current, items, groups, options);
      setDidLoad(true);
    }
  }, [didLoad, groups, items, options]);
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The way I handle this now is to put the appropriate dependencies in the list of dependencies.

Because I want the effect to run only one time, and because the effect only relies on some data when the component first mounts, it's perfectly fine to omit those dependencies. For example, the `groups` prop may change later, but this effect doesn't need to run again.

But, as a habit I don't omit the recommended dependencies and I always list them. If I were to intentionally omit something, I would add an eslint ignore statement... it's whatever convention you want to follow as long as you understand what is happening when that data changes and the effect does / does not run.

However the code I proposed, shown below, isn't the best solution if you do want to list the dependencies as it causes an extra render when `didLoad` changes.

```
 const [didLoad, setDidLoad] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!didLoad) {
      container.current = new VisTimeline(container.current, items, groups, options);
      setDidLoad(true);
    }
  }, [didLoad, groups, items, options]);
```

Instead of using state to track that the effect ran, I will use a ref (which doesn't need to be a dependency).

```
 const timelineLoaded = useRef<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!timelineLoaded.current) {
      container.current = new VisTimeline(container.current, items, groups, options);
      timelineLoaded.current = true;
    }
  }, [groups, items, options]);
```

Comment: good grief. i've been exclusively writing functional components for over a year now and i'm pretty frustrated with how messy some of the workarounds end up being. am i the only one that finds useEffect incredibly limiting?

Comment: @jpro Having written hundereds of `useEffect`s in production code I find it to be powerful and easier than class components lifecycle methods in the vast majority of cases and a little bit harder in some edge cases. Personally I'm fine with the trade-off and a lot of it is just experience. Once you had a few of the edge cases it gets easier to work around them. i can't agree that is is limiting compared to what we had before as you can implement the exact same behaviour with it. It's just a little more boilerplate in rare cases for the benefit of much less code in common cases.

Comment: This particular case is not a limitation of useEffect, but of eslint.

Comment: Things like these are a reason I really hate functional components. What used to be literally one line of code in class components requires 10 lines now.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment that the old component lifecycle syntax is easier to comprehend. I prefer it. I really want to like hooks and FCs for their "keep the logic for a domain in one place" aspect, but IMO, it makes the React code much harder to work with overall. Despite this, I think the use of refs for this use case is the best way (assuming you want to use FCs). Refs are contemporary React-idiom for "alive as long as your component lives"; by using them, you signal to your team mates and future self the real intent.

Answer (score 2):

Adding extra code to work around tooling is not good.

Solve the actual problem - in this case exclude the code you know works the way you want from the linter.

Specifically disable linting on the code where you know you do not want values in the `useEffect` dependency array. Add this above the `useEffect` code block:

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
```

Answer (score -3):

```
useEffect(() => {
    container.current = new VisTimeline(container.current, items, groups, options);
  }, [groups, items, options]);
```

The above code runs the function everytime one of the variables in the array changes. If you want to run this just once then `[]` should be the array as mentioned in the docs. So basically

```
useEffect(() => {
    container.current = new VisTimeline(container.current, items, groups, options);
  }, []);
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that ESLint is still going to complain, let alone that this is generally considered bad practice as far as I'm aware.

Comment: eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps by eslint throws a warning when dependencies are used the useeffect.